# Spring mvc jquery ui "accordion is not a function"

Tags: jquery-ui, spring-mvc, accordion

I have and accordion working on a normal html page, but when I try and add it to a Spring MVC page then I get the error: `$(...).accordion is not a function`.

**Here is the header of my `WEB-INF\views\index.jsp`file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
         <head>
  <title>Jeeni Software Ltd</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="css/style.css"/>" type="text/css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="css/menu/menu_style.css"/>" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"/>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js">"></script>       
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="js/jquery.flip.js"/>"></script>

...
<!-- This is the 'accordion' div -->
<div id="accordion" style="height:800px;">
   <h3>Title...</h3>
   ...
```

**Here is the ready function:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var object = $("#accordion");
  alert("object: "  + object.accordion);

  $("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: 'false', autoHeight: false });
  $("#banner").fadeIn(1000);

  alert("Done");
});
```

with this `alert("object: "  + object.accordion);` show `object: undefined` and it bombs out on the next line.

**Here is my `servlet-context.xml` file**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/cv/**" location="/cv/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/wow/**" location="/wow/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/imgs/**" location="/imgs/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/inc/**" location="/inc/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/article-imgs/**" location="/article-imgs/" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Firebug shows no problem loading any of the jquery files. I can re-create the proper behavior outside of Spring mvc, so the problem must be something to do with Spring/Java?!? But I can not find out what. The only error Firebug reports is the `$(...).accordion is not a function`, but everything is setup just like on the jquery ui accordion example.

BTW, I've trawled the internet for the last 3 hours and found similar problems that were fixed by typos. This isn't a typo error. I can not find anything like this regarding jquery UI and Spring MVC.

Comment: "This isn't a typo error" your setting yrself up needlessly there ...

Comment: Is it possible that you built/downloaded a custom build of UI and did not include `accordion` as one of the widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved!

The problem was that I was importing some content via:

```
<jsp:include page="../includes/index_page_intro_txt.jsp" />
```

and this JSP file was re-importing jquery. Took this out and everything was fine.

Special thanks to @NimChimpsky for being a sounding board and keeping me going.

There's no way anyone could have solved this with the information above. So just let you all know how I solved it:

I started by removing everything from the file other than the library imports, the ready statement and the accordion div block. Then it worked. So I slowly added everything back until it stopped working and then investigated that cause.

Should have done that in the first place - duh!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js">"></script>
```

is not correct in some way.

- Can you get any jquery functions to work ?
- Is it just the jquery-ui functions that are not working?
- Did you customize the jquery-ui download and not include accordion ?
- Do you get 404 in the browser debugger ?
- Are you opening a popup which overwrites the jQuery object with something else ?

Also probably better to use a cdn hosted version of the jQuery lib files. The below gets the latest version and works with accordion.

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: Tried all those. Still not working. the `/` is not needed because the  `c:url` is puts that on there for you. It does the path stuff with MVC.

Comment: @AdamDavies you have tried with a cdn hsoted version of jquery-ui and it doesn't work either ? I beg to differ. My edit shows a workign version that gets the latest released jquery ui

Comment: OK, done a clean and compile with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>` and `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>`. Still not working for me. It works fine in a raw html, just not with Spring MVC. Did you run it in a Spring container?

Comment: Spring has nothihg to do with this. You are using a js file hosted on a google server in an html document (which is created from your jsp file by tomcat/glassfish whatever). What are the answers to my bullet point questions ? If it still not working you must have a connection issue from yr server to the cdn, as that jquer js file defintiely works with accordion, or you are opening a pop up which overwrites the jquer object withone that doesn;t include accordion